# macOS Sierra: AppleScript mount volume keeps asking for login

Tags: applescript, mount, disk-volume, macos

For several OS X versions I've used:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e mount volume "smb://yourserver" as user name  "yourusername" with password “yourpassword”
```

This has worked great, a nice and quiet mount of the network share, if it is available of course.

Now recently I installed macOS Sierra (10.12 public beta, build 16A238m), and the script still works, however it will now suddenly always show a login dialog, pre-populated with the "yourusername" and "yourpassword" values. The user will still have to click "Connect" to mount the share.

Does anyone know if this is a "bug" in the beta version (I did report this with Apple's Feedback app), or is this expected and/or what would be the "fix" for that?

See also: [AppleScript Documentation "mount volume"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW17)

Comment: It could be related to the fact Apple have locked down the `/Volumes` folder where the network share is mounted to root access only, requiring user authorization to create the mount point.
Unfortunately I don't know of a work around at the moment, though I'm going to play with modifying sudoers on the computer.
I have an Open Radar at https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4948585099558912 wheren Apple have confirmed it's locked down.

Comment: You could also mount it directly with `open`, and giving the user name and password in the URL. See "method 2" in my [other answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399035/14586)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Apple replied to the ticket referenced in mattdwen's [Open Radar link](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4948585099558912) above, as of macOS Sierra 10.12,

> you can no longer create items in /Volumes unless root.

Further, my best understanding of the AppleScript [mount volume](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW17) command is that it doesn't have a way to specify the mount point and consequently it **only** mounts volumes under `/Volumes` through the Finder's standard mechanism. So, I don't think you can do it via AppleScript.

**But there's another way.** You can accomplish the same thing using the lower level `mount` command:

```
mkdir -p ~/mnt
mount_smbfs "//my_username:my_password@my_hostname/share" ~/mnt
```

After mounting the volume this way, you should see a normal "volume" icon appear on your desktop and the `~/mnt` directory will appear as "share" when you browse your user directory via Finder.

The one thing missing from this approach is saving the login credentials in Keychain. To do that, you have to do a bit more scripting. Something like this.

Save the password:

```
security add-generic-password -a my_username -s my_hostname -w my_password
```

Retrieve the password and mount the share:

```
pass=$(security find-generic-password -a my_username -s my_hostname -w)
mount_smbfs "//my_username:${pass}@my_hostname/share" ~/mnt
```

NOTE: If you have special characters in your password, you will probably need to URL encode it, perhaps like this:

```
pass='my !@#%%^& password'
pass=$(php -r "echo urlencode(\"$pass\");")
>>> my+%21%40%23%25%25%5E%26+password
```

Comment: Thank you mnewt and mattdwen!
This should be a good work around! (and possible a better one than using AppleScript)

Comment: presumably this approach would break anything that references files under `/Volumes/share`?

Comment: It definitely would break anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed by Apple in macOS Sierra 10.12.2:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207112

Comment: There is a typo in their "undo" example. The correct "undo" way would be: `sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization AllowUnknownServers` (removed the "write" in that line).